# I want to create an array structure of a string and an integer in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

```
struct arr 
{char * str;
 int ctr;
}m_arr[100];
```

The problem I am facing is whenever I insert a value into string and int field and I traverse through the array to print, the `int` field displays correctly but my string field is always the last one I updated.

For ex: The values I pass are `{'t-1',2} and {'t-2',5}`.

When I use a for loop to display the array elements I get `{'t-2',2}` and `{'t-2',5}`.

Where am I going wrong?

I first tried using a queue and had the same problem. So implementing using an array but again the same problem. Please help. Very urgent.

Comment: Can you show your actual code? I bet you're just copying the pointer rather than using `strdup()` or some other mechanism for persisting the real values.

Comment: Can we see more of the code where you assign values to your array?

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate space for the string somewhere.  It's easiest to do that in the structure:

```
struct arr 
{
    char str[32];
    int  ctr;
} m_arr[100];
```

but you could also do it by dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` et al (or using `strdup()`).

With the structure shown, you copy the string you read into the `m_arr[i].str` using `strcpy()` or an equivalent.  Remember to ensure that the string is not too long for the data.  One advantage of `strdup()` is and dynamic allocation is that the string can always be made big enough.

Answer (score 1):

You problem here is that you don't actually store the string in there. You're just keeping a pointer pointing to it. I assume the value you actually print is some temporary string you've used to fill it.

The easiest fix would be using a string rather than a pointer:

```
struct arr
{
    char str[10]; // able to hold up to 9 characters + terminating \0
    int ctr;
} m_arr[100];
```

To actually store a string you'd have to copy it, e.g. using `strcpy()` or `sprintf()`.